# Calling a javascript function and pass value to function from partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have defined a function `formatPrice` in accountJS file, which I want to call while binding jquery datatable in a partial view. Along with that I want to pass the `@item.price` value to this function.

Below is the code:

```
@model List<Products>

<table id="datatableResult" class="searchgrid">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Product Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@if (Model != null)
{
     foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
         <td>@item.Id</td>
         <td>accountJS.formatPrice(@item.price)</td>
      </tr>
    }
 }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<td>accountJS.formatPrice(@item.price)</td>` => this function call is totally wrong because it's not called inside JS `<script>` block. Which event you want to trigger using `@item.price` value?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - Can you please guide me how it should be called ?<script>accounting.formatMoney(@item.acc_total_balance)</script> it does not work

Comment: The first thing you should have is the script embedding tag: `<script src="~/path/to/accountJS.js"></script>`. Then inside JS script tag you may call `formatPrice()` with row data, but I want to know how you trigger the `formatPrice()` for corresponding row (using action link or other elements).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - The file gets included in main View. So I dont think I will have to add <script src="~/path/to/accountJS.js">. So I expect while rendering the datatable, the Price will be pass to fomatPrice function which should Format the price. No Action required as this code I want to write while binding the DataTable.

Comment: I think you can use `formatPrice()` inside [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option, e.g. `render: function (data, type, row, meta) { formatPrice(...); }`. But you cannot use `@item.price` outside `foreach` scope (i.e. inside script tag), thus it is necessary to pass the row object instead.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - I tried Render function, but it only prints the function with data while rendering the datatable column, so what I can see in Column is  AccountJS.formatPrice(100). Its not calling JS function

Comment: You should set the row as `<td>@item.price</td>`, and use client-side formatting inside `render` function. The `@item.price` value can be passed using column index contained inside `row` parameter, e.g. `render: function (data, type, row, meta) { return formatPrice(row[1]); }`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - Thanks a lot. render with few simple straight forward code worked for me. Adding code for reference `code'  "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 1,
                "render": function (data, type, row,meta) {
                    return accountJS.formatPrice( row[1]);
                }
            }]

Comment: Yes, that's what I expected by using `row` parameter from `render` function setting. I added an answer to show what you should do from the start.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I had seen, `accountJS.formatPrice(@item.price)` is not a valid function call because it was called outside the `<script>` block, and rendered as plain text. Therefore, the table element must be set as follows:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
         <td>@item.Id</td>
         <td>@item.price</td>
      </tr>
    }
}
```

Then, in `DataTable` function you can use column index from `row` parameter inside `render` setting to get the price and pass it to external JS function:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#datatableResult').DataTable({
        // other settings

        columnDefs": [{ 
           "targets": 1, 
           "render": function (data, type, row, meta) { 
               // pass the column index here
               return accountJS.formatPrice(row[1]); 
           } 
        }]

        // other settings
    });
});
<script>
```

Reference:

[DataTable - Column rendering](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

Related issue:

[Jquery Datatables How to get column Id in render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922492/jquery-datatables-how-to-get-column-id-in-render-function)